# How does this C++ template member function declaration work?

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a snippet from the [documentation of the Boost.Reflect library](http://bytemaster.github.io/boost_reflect/group__boost__reflect__quickstart.html):

```
template<typename T>
struct xml_printer {
    xml_printer( const T& c ):self(c){}

    template<typename Type> 
    static xml_printer<Type> make( const Type& t ) {
        return xml_printer<Type>(t);
    }

    template<typename Member, typename Class, Member Class::*p>
    void operator()( const char* name )const {
        std::cerr<<"<"<<name<<">"<<(self.*p)<<"</"<<name<<">\n";
    }
    const T& self;
};
```

The part I'm confused about is the declaration of `operator()` in the visitor:

```
template<typename Member, typename Class, Member Class::*p>
void operator()( const char* name )const
```

Particularly the `Member Class::*p` part. If I understand correctly, this type parameter is in place in order for the visitor to be able to resolve the member, and this is the type information which the library stores somehow for the member. However, it looks very unusual to me with two types written after each other. Could you explain to me how this works or perhaps provide an example that would call a function with such declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member Class::*p` it's pointer to member of class `Class` with type `Member`.
So, something like this will call it's true

```
auto printer = xml_printer<T>();
printer.template operator()<int, T, &T::x>("x");
```

where `x` is member variable of type `T` with type `int`.

From docs, that you link

```
#define BOOST_REFLECT_VISIT_MEMBER( r, visitor, elem ) \
visitor.template operator()
<BOOST_TYPEOF(type::elem),type,&type::elem>( BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`Member Class::*p` means that `p` is a pointer to `Class` member of type `Member`.

It's unrelated to template declarations, it's just a C++ syntax for pointer-to-member declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to members are valid template arguments (see C++11 standard 14.1/4).

You'd call it like this:

```
xml_printer<foo> printer;
printer.operator()<some_type, foo, &foo::bar>("some string literal");
```